# What is the BLEU score used in Google Brain's "Attention Is All You Need" paper?

Tags: neural-network, machine-translation

Google Brain's [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper on sequence-to-sequence translation reports:

> Our model achieves 28.4 BLEU on the WMT 2014 Englishto-German
>   translation task, improving over the existing best results, including
>   ensembles, by over 2 BLEU

but the [Wikipedia entry on BLEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU) says:

> BLEU’s output is always a number between 0 and 1

What definition of BLEU is the Google Brain paper using? I could not find a separate definition in the paper itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BLEU (Bi Lingual Evaluation Understudy) is an algorithm for evaluating the quality of text which has been machine-translated (MT) from one natural language to another. BLEU is typically measured on a 0 to 1 scale, with 1 as the hypothetical “perfect” translation.

Google uses the same definition of BLEU but multiplies the typical score by 100.